# problems in inserting datas on mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

PDO noob here! 
I had tried this script with a sqlite file and it works perfectly, but not I have switched to a mysql database and it gives problem, without entering the data into the database.

(_db.php file)

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=prova_schedule;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';

$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

(insert.php)

```
<?php
require_once '_db.php';

$insert = "INSERT INTO events (name, start, end) VALUES (:name, :start, :end)";

$stmt = $db->prepare($insert);

$stmt->bindParam(':start', $_POST['start']);
$stmt->bindParam(':end', $_POST['end']);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);


$stmt->execute();

class Result {}

$response = new Result();
$response->result = 'OK';
$response->message = 'Created with id: '.$db->lastInsertId();

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Sincerly  I have no idea why it's not working anymore properly with a mysql database.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Like a reserved keyword error, perhaps?

Comment: Turn on error reporting.  Let PHP do the work and tell you what is wrong.  On the surface the code looks fine to me.

Comment: which "reserved" keyword is that? I don't see one. Keywords yes; reserved, no. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: I tried with a try when it does the $stmt->execute();
the Error given to me is: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: OK, solved! basically the ID row of my database wasn't autoincrement, I just set it and it works fine! Thank you all, you never stop learning (expecially if you're new!)

Answer (score 0):

The word "events" is a reserved word in at least 1 version of MySQL so you'll need to put back-ticks around it so that it looks like:

```
`events`
```

The MySQL website has a section where you can look up what words are reserved words for a given version of MySQL.

Comment: thank you for pointing out, good to remember! I changed all the variable names but still it doesn't work.. I think I'll convert all in mysql language which I know more about!